# .NET Core self-contained deployment (SCD) in one file

Tags: deployment, .net-core

If I create a .NET Core self-contained deployment (SCD) ...

```
dotnet new console
dotnet publish -c RELEASE -r linux-x64
```

... I get a folder with 186 files.

[image]

(List of all files https://gist.github.com/dhcgn/15e3cf44b2e0c76e8b8d76d32e01f4e7)

How can I pack these files in **one executable** for linux?

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7737. Basically, it will rely on CoreRT. I am not sure if that is production ready yet.

Comment: Oh, and with the linker, you can get down to a few dozen files instead of hundreds: https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/30

Comment: What about 'packer for executables' is there not a simple tool to pack a bunch of files with the possibility to execute?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
There is an open feature request for [publishing a dotnet application to one self contained executable file](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7737)

**Original Answer**
Short answer, to my knowledge, is that you can't get a "single file" self contained deployment package.

The generated directory contains your self contained deployment package with a linux executable file that matches your project name. That executable will run on a compatible Linux server without installed dependencies. [Scott Hanselman did a nice write up about self contained deployments](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx).